# Python shelve file extension on CentOS

Tags: python, centos6, shelve

When I use python shelve on Ubuntu, it saves to a file without extension. But when I use it on CentOS, 3 files appears with extensions .bac .dat and .dir. What happens here and how to make them consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shelve` uses behind the scene the `dbm` module, which in turns uses some native `dbm` bindings depending on the OS.

Citing the docs:

> dbm is a generic interface to variants of the DBM database — dbm.gnu or dbm.ndbm. If none of these modules is installed, the slow-but-simple implementation in module dbm.dumb will be used.

Therefore, depending on the OS you are using and what's installed on it, it might be saved in different ways.

Shameful self-promotion: I made an alternative for `shelve` which you may find handy since it is platform independent: https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos